# Bricked 14" HP Pavilion X360m laptop - A cautionary tale of lost passwords

Tags: bios, passwords, uefi, reset

Best I can tell is I just bricked my laptop. A 14" HP Pavilion X360m Convertible (Model: 14m-cd0005dx). Any help at recovery would be GREATLY appreciated.

I lost my passwords several months ago and I've been slowly recovering them. That's another story.

What happened to the laptop is I was trying to recover the BIOS/UEFI admin password to the laptop and I thought *wrongly* I could remove the battery and the CMOS settings would reset including the passwords. The CMOS did reset but when I read follow-up conversations I found out the passwords are saved in the firmware and not the CMOS.

I thought oh dang. Well at least I have the user password and I can still use the laptop. Nope. I'm thinking when I reset the CMOS it also lost the time and day settings and now I can't boot to anything except the BIOS login screen because I can't set the date and time. It's not accepting the user password anymore either. I tried to boot to an external drive with no luck. It looks like my best chance at data recovery is to remove the HDD and read it from an external drive adapter. Yet another story.

- Does anyone have any idea how I can reset my firmware and recover my laptop? Right now the laptop is useless as it is.
- Is there a way to restore the firmware to the factory settings? I tried the BIOS Master Password Generator site but the only entry I can make is the BIOS login screen. Is that where I need to enter the code they generate?
- How would I access another way? Is my best bet to get a "new" motherboard?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes it is a cautionary tale. I wish someone had posted this information before. 

The entire last paragraph is questions. Do you know how I can reset my firmware? How do I enter the code generated on the Password Generator site. Is my best option to get a new motherboard?

Comment: No idea. Best bet? Sell it for parts. If you can get data you need off of the internal storage, good. Count your blessings. But otherwise? Sell the system for parts. Sorry to say, that is the best that can be done.

Answer (score 3):

When there is a firmware password on the system, the only way to remove it is to reprogram the BIOS/firmware. In order to do that, you need to be able to remove the motherboard, desolder the BIOS chip, connect it to a programmer, find and download an original BIN file for the BIOS for your laptop, reprogram it and solder it back on. That is the only way.

When you removed the CMOS battery, what likely happened was that the BIOS settings reset itself along with the boot settings as well which is now preventing you from booting up into the hard drive.

Your best and probably only bet is to take your device to a reliable repair company who can do what I've mentioned above, fix the boot settings on the firmware, and get it to work.

You can still remove the hard drive and recover the data by plugging it into another dock or reader unless you have placed a HDD/SSD password as well. If you had enabled BitLocker encryption on your drive which syncs a 48-digit key with Microsoft, you may need to get that first to retrieve your data.

Comment: Yes, UEFI Password will be stored on the BIOS chip which is on the Motherboard. Replacement of the motherboard resolves that issue but a reliable repair shop shouldn't charge you more than 145-175£ in the UK or more than 200$ internationally. Some countries, it would be even cheaper.

Comment: Found a used motherboard on Amazon for about $25. It comes with a guarantee so low risk. And I'm comfortable doing the replacement. I can finally replace the failing battery too!